# Adjective clause construction

Tags: sentence-construction

> All those pipelines you monitored yesterday I need their report in my office today.

Is the above sentence correct? I am concerned about "their" in the second clause, which refers back to the pipelines.

Comment: Your text does reflect the way people often *speak*, but it's not a grammatically valid "sentence". Structurally, it's [Noun phrase] [Statement referencing "noun phrase"], same as, for example, ***My wife I love her***. To make it syntactically valid you need to include the noun phrase ***within*** the statement. For example: ***I love my wife***, or in your case, *I need the report on all those pipelines you monitored yesterday in my office today*.

Comment: Note that this "ungrammatical" introduction of the "subject" before a statement often occurs in speech because it's an easy way for the speaker to focus the listener's attention on that specific thing ***before*** hearing the immediately-following statement that's going to refer back to it. You'll very often hear the construction preceded by ***You know*** ("eye-dialect" ***yunno***), which "massages" the utterance into a syntactically valid sequence: ***You know my wife? I love her.*** / ***You know all those pipelines you monitored...?***

Comment: Just put a dash in there, and it'll be fine. **All those pipelines you monitored yesterday  -- I need their report in my office today.**

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is comprehensible, but it is not strictly grammatical. It is typical of spoken English, particularly hurried spoken English, and email. "All ... yesterday" is neither subject nor object and is intended to identify the desired report without any explicit syntactical connection to "report." Furthermore, "their" is nonsense because pipelines cannot give a report at any time. "In my office" is a vague way to stress rhetorically the urgency of both completion and delivery of the report. The intended meaning is

> As early today as possible, you must deliver to me your completed report on those pipelines that you monitored yesterday.

I stress that, particularly in spoken English, utterances that are not strictly grammatical are common. That is one reason for misunderstandings.