# Possesive pronoun used after relative clause

Tags: sentence-construction

1. The man who came at yesterday's party, his car has been stolen at GIP Market.

I want to Express that   a man came in a yesterday's party and his car has been stolen by some one  from GIP Market.so is the above sentence is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of your own earlier question [Adjective clause construction](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/224816/adjective-clause-construction) *(All those pipelines you monitored yesterday I need their report in my office today)*. This question is about *exactly* the same thing (an "ungrammatical noun phrase" followed by a reference back to that NP in a syntactically valid "sentence". It's a feature of relaxed conversational usage that ignores strict grammar).

Comment: Please tell us why you think your sentence is incorrect?

Comment: Because the man's car was stolen,he came to the yesterday's party.